# Generador de contraseñas in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, vba

hice un generador de contraseñas en Visual Basic, pero solo puede colocar letras y numeros, no puede colocar simbolos y si colocolo los simbolos en Dim Charlist, no los pone.

¿Hay alguna manera de que coloque los simbolos?

```
Public Class Form2
Dim UsableChars() As String
Dim RandomClass As New Random()
Dim CharsList = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0"
Dim FinalPassword As String = ""
Dim Number As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    UsableChars = Split(CharsList, ",")
    FinalPassword = ""
    Number = 0

    If IsNumeric(txtLength.Text) Then
        If txtLength.Text > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 1 To txtLength.Text
                Number = RandomClass.Next(0, 61)
                FinalPassword = FinalPassword + UsableChars(Number)
            Next
            txtPassword.Text = FinalPassword
        Else
            MsgBox("Coloque un numero mayor a cero", vbInformation, "Excepcion")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("El dato colocado no es un numero o esta vacio. Coloque un numero", vbInformation, "Excepcion")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If txtPassword.Text = String.Empty Then
        MsgBox("El campo donde debe estar la contraseña esta vacio", vbInformation, "Excepcion")
    Else
        Clipboard.SetText(txtPassword.Text)
        MsgBox("Se copio la contraseña, salvela en un archivo .txt (Usando notepad) o en un documento de Word", vbInformation, "Resultado")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    MsgBox("Coloque un numero en el campo de texto y presione el botón de generar. Luego copie su resultado en el campo de texto más grande", vbInformation, "Instrucciones")
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hola Shredder. No está claro lo que pides. Has de mostrar datos que intentas procesar y que comportamiento está sucediendo asi como el deseado. Y explicar la depuracion  o mostrar trazas de errores. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: @Shredder Te da algun error o has probado hacer con variables String??

Comment: No da errores, solamente no los muestra en el textbox. No he usado stribgs.

Answer (score 0):

intenta utilizando la funcion chr(), te dejo un enlace.
[funcion chr microsoft](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/car-funci%C3%B3n-chr-94e7d144-8ba7-4082-8519-e5dd1b451b85?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES)

tambien un listado de los codigos chr para dicha funcion, siempre verifica que sea el simbolo que quieres pues segun la codificacion, puede resultar que te muestre otro.
[listado codigos chr](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/strings-characters/ascii-characters.htm)